# CSS Animation stop working when jekyll building with JEKYLL_ENV production

Tags: build, css-animations, jekyll, github-pages

I have a jekyll page that I host on GitHub pages, and I'd like to add a few animations to it. More specifically, I tried to add the animations that are displayed in [this blog post](https://antfu.me/posts/sliding-enter-animation). I basically replicated some of the code provided there, more specifically:

```css
@keyframes enter {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}

[data-animate] {
  --stagger: 0;
  --delay: 120ms;
  --start: 0ms;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  [data-animate] {
    animation: enter 0.6s both;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--stagger) * var(--delay) + var(--start));
  }
}

[data-animation-controller="false"] [data-animate] {
  animation: none;
}
```

And then use it by adding `style="--stagger: 1;" data-animate` to elements like these:

```html
<h1 class="post-title" style="--stagger: 1;" data-animate>Test 1</h1>
<p class="desc" style="--stagger: 2;" data-animate>Test 2</p>
```

The animation runs smooth when I build the site locally and run in a local server with:

```bash
bundle exec jekyll build --lsi
python3 -m http.server -d _site/
```

But if before building and running I run `export JEKYLL_ENV=production` (which is what I do before uploading to GitHub pages), the animation stop doing the steps one by one, and run like everyone should appear at the same time. How can I fix this? I checked the code and both the `style` and the css configuration are there.